# Tabla de posiciones en Java

Tags: java

Mi problema es el siguiente. Ya logré que la tabla de posiciones me ejecutara los equipos, ordenados de forma ascendente, por puntos, pero, no logro hacer como me haga lo mismo con la diferencia de goles (dfg), sin que me afecte la posicion del equipo. Ejemplo:

```
POS|    EQUIPO   |PJ |PG |PE |PP |GF |GC |DFG|PTS
1. | Millonarios | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3
11.| Envigado    | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |-1 | 0
```

Se supone que por el orden de puntos, teniendo en cuenta que los demas equipos no han jugado y tienen 0 puntos, "Envigado", deberia quedar en el puesto 19, con 0 puntos, pero su diferencia de goles es de -1, pero, segun me ejecuta el codigo, sale en el puesto 11, por el orden alfabetico. Aqui dejo el código:

```
    package arraylist.fpc;

    import java.util.Arrays;


    public class Futbol  {
        static class Equipo implements Comparable <Equipo>{
        public String equipo;
        public int pj;
        public int pg;
        public int pe;
        public int pp;
        public int gf;
        public int gc;
        public int dfg;
        public int pts;
     
        public Equipo(String equipo, int pj, int pg, int pe, int pp, int gf, int gc, int dfg, int pts){
            this.equipo = equipo;
            this.pj = pj;
            this.pg = pg;
            this.pe = pe;
            this.pp = pp;
            this.gf = gf;
            this.gc = gc;
            this.dfg = dfg;
            this.pts = pts;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Equipo e) {
            Integer a = this.pts;
            Integer b = e.pts;
            return b.compareTo(a);
    }
           
    static void imprimirArrayEquipos(Equipo[] array){
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1) + ".| " + array[i].equipo + " | " + array[i].pj + " | " + array[i].pg + " | " + array[i].pe + " | " + array[i].pp + " | " + array[i].gf + " | " + array[i].gc + " | " + array[i].dfg + " | " + array[i].pts);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Equipo[] arrayEquipos = new Equipo[19];
        arrayEquipos[0] = new Equipo("Alianza Petrolera", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        arrayEquipos[1] = new Equipo("America de Cali", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        arrayEquipos[2] = new Equipo("Atletico Nacional", 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3);
        arrayEquipos[3] = new Equipo("Atletico Bucaramanga", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        arrayEquipos[4] = new Equipo("Boyaca Chico", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        arrayEquipos[5] = new Equipo("Deportes Tolima", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        arrayEquipos[6] = new Equipo("Deportivo Cali", 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3);
        arrayEquipos[7] = new Equipo("Deportivo Pasto", 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1);
        arrayEquipos[8] = new Equipo("Deportivo Pereira", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        arrayEquipos[9] = new Equipo("Envigado", 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0);
        arrayEquipos[10] = new Equipo("Independiente Medellin", 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0);
        arrayEquipos[11] = new Equipo("Independiente Santa Fe", 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, -2, 0);
        arrayEquipos[12] = new Equipo("Jaguares de Cordoba", 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0);
        arrayEquipos[13] = new Equipo("Junior", 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3);
        arrayEquipos[14] = new Equipo("La Equidad", 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1);
        arrayEquipos[15] = new Equipo("Once Caldas", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        arrayEquipos[16] = new Equipo("Millonarios", 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3);
        arrayEquipos[17] = new Equipo("Patriotas", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        arrayEquipos[18] = new Equipo("Rionegro", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        
        /*System.out.println("POS|    EQUIPO  |PJ|PG|PE|PP|GF|GC|DFG|PTS");
        imprimirArrayEquipos(arrayEquipos);*/
        
        Arrays.sort(arrayEquipos);
        System.out.println("POS|    EQUIPO  |PJ|PG|PE|PP|GF|GC|DFG|PTS");
        imprimirArrayEquipos(arrayEquipos);
    }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo hago para solucionar este error, que el codigo me tome tambie la diferencia de goles, pero los puntos no me los afecte?

Gracias

Comment: Eso falla porque pusiste a Millonarios primero :P  Nomentiras, la clave es la respuesta de jramonmartinez: hay que crear un comparador que revise los atributos de las dos instancias de Equipo y diga cuál es "mayor" de acuerdo a los criterios que definas. Java no sabe cómo ordenar Equipos

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo tu implementación, puedes añadir una condición más a la redefinición del compareTo, en concreto:

```
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Equipo e) {
            Integer a = this.pts;
            Integer b = e.pts;
            if(b.compareTo(a)==0) {
                Integer x = this.dfg;
                Integer y = e.dfg;
                return y.compareTo(x);
            }else
            return b.compareTo(a);
        }
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Sería útil que le indicaras cómo usar el comparador (que puede no ser trivial para el OP si no lo ha usado antes). Y si le puedes indicar cómo poner más de un parámetro de comparación.

Comment: Sí, totalmente. Lo haré en próximas respuestas. Gracias

Comment: Más que hacerlo en próximas respuestas, podrías ***editar*** esta y añadir esa información... Además, usar nombres de variables **explicativos** es también muy importante a la hora de intentar enseñar algo a otros que puede que no sepan muy bien lo que están leyendo. Ver un montón de variables `a`, `b`, `x`, `y`... no ayuda. En cambio si les pones nombres como `thisDfg`, `otroDfg` (por ejemplo) es mucho más fácil entenderlo

Comment: Hay posibilidad para agregar mas condiciones IF en el mismo compareTo??

Answer (score 0):

El método compareTo() determina el orden natural de tus objetos Equipo.

En este caso el orden natural (según tu criterio) es:
puntos -> DFG (de mayor a menor).

```
@Override
 public int compareTo(Equipo e) {

    int ord = Integer.compare(e.pts, this.pts);

    if(ord != 0) {
    // si es distinto de 0 ya encontramos un orden
        return ord;
    } else {
    // buscamos el orden según diferencia de gol
        return Integer.compare(e.dfg, this.dfg);
    }
    
}
```

Cuando se ejecute Arrays.sort(arrayEquipos) el algoritmo utilizará compareTo() para determinar el orden de los elementos del array (en este caso el orden natural). Si se busca otro orden se puede usar la interface **Comparator** y pasar un segundo parámetro a *Arrays.sort(array, miComparador).*

Detalles a tener en cuenta:

Debe lanzar un *NullPointerException* si el parámetro **e** es nulo. Es lo primero que se debe evaluar.

```
if(e == null) throw new NullPointerException("mensaje");
```

Es preferible que el resultado de compareTo() sea consistente con equals() para los mismos objetos. Si *ob1.equals(ob2)* es *true*  entonces *ob1.compareTo(o2)* es *0*.

Idealmente, se deben incluir todos los campos de la clase en el método compareTo() para tener un orden total y lograr consistencia con equals(). En tu caso que pasa si pts y dfg son iguales para dos equipos.

Se debe cumplir la propiedad [transitiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaci%C3%B3n_transitiva) .

Se debe cumplir la propiedad [simétrica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaci%C3%B3n_sim%C3%A9trica), es decir *a.compareTo(b)* es igual a *b.compareTo(a)*.

Y si *a* y *b* son iguales entonces dado otro elemento *c* se debe cumplir que *a.compareTo(c)*  y  *b.compareTo(c)* arrojan el mismo resultado.

Comment: Gracias, la info me sirvio de mucho